# Finding the name of excel file from xla

Tags: excel, vba, add-in

I am using an `xla` file to run my vba-code in excel. I have many templates, which use this `xla` file. Is there any way to find which template runs(opens) the `xla` file from `xla`.

I have used:

```
ThisWorkbook.FullName
```

but it returns the name of the `xla` file and not the name of the template

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question fully... Does the `xla` file create the templates? Or do you just regularly use the templates in tandem with the functions and routines you have stored in the `xla` file? Anyway, you can check out which `Workbooks` are open by looping through `Application.Workbooks` like this: `For Each wb In Application.Workbooks`

Comment: well `ThisWorkbook` *always* refers to *This* workbook, i.e., the workbook in which the VBA resides.  `ActiveWorkbook` would refer to the currently *Active* workbook, which you might be able to leverage, with an event-handler but it is hard to say. Can you add a more detailed explanation of the use-case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a straightforward way for a `Function` or a `Sub` to find out who's calling it (because the call/stack tracing is not available programatically to VBA).

You could do your own tracing, by implementing some `push` and `pop` operations on a custom-made stack globally accessible in your `.xla`, for example. When a function is called, it pushes its filename+module+name to the stack, and when it ends it pops that information from the stack.

But then again, it depends on the "benevolence" of the calling function (e.g. the one from the file that references your `.xla` file) to use your tracing convention. Also, it might make your code more brittle. And also, it could make it worse actually, if you don't handle *every* exception that might break the execution of your functions/subs.

See also this (last section): http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx